# Show only subcategories on category page (Opencart 2.0)

Tags: php, opencart

Is there a way, or an extension, in opencart 2.0.1.1 that will modify the Category module so it only displays the current top level category page's sub-categories.

For example, if I am on the "Laptops & Desktops" category page, the sidebar module would only list the sub-categories associated with "Laptops & Desktops" category, such as "Macs" and "PCs" with the main heading "Laptops & Desktops" (And not list or show any of the other top level categories).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the modules from the link below and set the modules which will show Show only subcategories on category page.

[Show only subcategories on category page OpenCart 2.0 free module](https://webocreation.com/blog/show-only-subcategories-on-category-page-opencart-2-0-free-module)

Taking your requirement into consideration you should disable Category module and activate "Only Sub-Categories"